Dotenv cannot use nodejs typescript
I had a problem with the env configuration and this my code.
I have consulted some solutions, but still can not solve the problem. Can you help me?

{
 ...
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.45.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.21.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.7.9",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3"
  }
}


tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es2016",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "lib": ["es6"],   
    "module": "ESNext",                             /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "rootDir": "/",                                    /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    "moduleResolution": "node10",  
    "resolveJsonModule": true,   
   "allowJs": true,    
   "outDir": "build", 
    "esModuleInterop": true,    
   "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }

}

version
nodejs: 21.6.1
i use
node --env-file=.env ./ĩndex.ts
error:
Error: Cannot find module '/backend/ĩndex.ts'

The question wasn't improved since https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79124795 . "If you run just node ./index.ts, is it still failing or is it working?" "yes". A good sense of humour doesn't solve all problems

You appear to be trying to run .ts files with node. This is not a supported (see "Introduction to TypeScript" on nodejs.org) file extension. You should be using .js or .mjs file extensions for Node.js.
The one key caveat there is that in Node@v22, there is experimental support for .ts, using the --experimental-strip-types flag, which is documented on the 4th page of that section of the docs.
